# Script works in terminal but not when ran using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, python, bash, processbuilder

I am trying to run a script using ProcessBuilder

The problem arises when in the script I am exporting to $PYTHONPATH to allow me to pipe an echo command into a python file shown below:

ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "sasa_script.sh");
                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                builder.directory(new File("/Users/me/script_location"));               
                Process process = builder.start();
```

sasa_script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/me/dir_for_tool/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/me/dir_for_tool/dir_containing_init.py/
echo $PYTHONPATH
echo -e"This is a sample echo." | python ./bin/classifyFromCmdLine.py
```

The script runs perfectly in mac terminal but when ran with ProcessBuilder causes the error where it ask you to run setup or set your PYTHONPATH (not an error with processBuilder but with the script)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/classifyFromCmdLine.py", line 22, in 
    "(or add the sasa-tool directory to PYTHONPATH, ie export PYTHONPATH=)?")
ImportError: Did you try to run '. setup.env'?
(or add the sasa-tool directory to PYTHONPATH, ie export PYTHONPATH=)?

I am also echoing PYTHONPATH which shows that after that command the right path was set.

So basically I am just wondering what Process builder does differently so that exporting before running the command cannot find the PYTHONPATH and how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try actually building the program as an exe jar and run it from the terminal. Then everything should share the same env variables.

Comment: It does and it works! But why doesn't it work in java? Clearly I need to look deeper into how ProcessBuilder runs scripts and how environment variables can be used. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you log in to a shell, your $PYTHONPATH environment variable is set somehow (probably via .bashrc or a similar profile config). When you run ProcessBuilder, this environment variable is not being set. You could either hardcode your PYTHONPATH into the script, or you could try using **source** to import the config and set the variable:

```
source /Users/me/.bashrc
```

Comment: Alright I completely understand why its resetting. So by hardcoding to you mean not using the $PYTHONPATH bit and doing something more like :
`export PYTHONPATH="/Users/me/dir_tool/subDir/`

I will also try editing my bash profile to add it if that would also make sense?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by hardcoding.

Comment: It gives the same output when it is hardcoded unfortunately, but as this was just a test project I think I might just deal with having to export the jar for now. If I fix it in the IDE I will update this question. Thanks for the help in understanding the problem.